# CUDA Thrust - Selective copy or replace with constant value

Tags: cuda, thrust, gpu

I have a requirement where I want to parallelize the following using CUDA thrust.

```
std::vector<float> a, b, c; // size of each is (size.x * size.y * size.z), kind of a 3D array.
```

What I am trying to do is this

```
   a[i] = 0 if b[i] < 0
   a[i] = c[i] if b[i] > 0
```

This is the host code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size.x; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < size.y; j++)
        for (int z = 0; z < size.z; z++) {
            a.data[get_idx(i, j, z)] = (b.data[get_idx(i, j, z)] < 0) ?
                                        (0) : (1 * c.data[get_idx(i, j, z)]);
        }
```

`get_idx()` just converts the loop indices to array indices.

What I want is an equivalent thrust::api that does this.
I have the thrust::device_vector ready with the values of the corresponding a, b, c cudaCopied to the host.

```
thrust::device_vector<float> dev_a, dev_b, dev_c;
```

What I have tried is to use `thrust::for_each` but I am unable to find a way to assign `dev_c[i]` to `dev_a[i]`.

I would love a nudge in the right direction, maybe which thrust:api is the most suitable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `thrust::transform`

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more digging around, I found the correct thrust api.

[thrust::replace_copy_if](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__replacing_ga1559ee22d3d642d29eccf2b049143851.html#ga1559ee22d3d642d29eccf2b049143851)

It is an overload of replace_copy_if which takes as input a 'stencil' which acts as the condition based on which value is copied.

In my case, 'b' is the stencil.

The following code works now.

```
struct is_less_than_zero
{
    __host__ __device__ bool operator()(float x)
    {
        return x < 0;
    }
};


is_less_than_zero pred{};

thrust::replace_copy_if(thrust::device, c.begin(), c.end(),
                        b.begin(), a.begin(), pred(), 0);
```